# How to fix this procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first time creating a sql procedure, and i need some help. 
What i am trying to do is to create a procedure that returns true or false if the user has correctly inputed his email and password

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE login(IN email varchar(50), IN password varchar(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @email VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @password VARCHAR(50);
    IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = @email AND password = @password) = 0, 'true', 'false');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@email VARCHAR(50);
>       DECLARE @password VARCHAR(50);
>       IF((SELECT COUNT(id' at line 3

This is the error message, i am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: What is this code attempting to do?  There are no output parameters or print statements.  It defines local variables but doesn't assign them.  It appears to be using unencrypted passwords.

Comment: Whats `==` in (My)SQL ?  i can't remember seeing `==` in MySQL's [Operators list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example will help you:

```
create table Test(Pass varchar(100), Mail varchar(100));
insert into Test(Pass, Mail) values('Pass1', "Email1");
insert into Test(Pass, Mail) values('Pass2', "Email2");
insert into Test(Pass, Mail) values('Pass3', "Email3");


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS loginFunction;
DELIMITER go
CREATE FUNCTION login(p_Pass char(100), p_Mail char(100)) RETURNS boolean
BEGIN

 declare countUser int;    
 DECLARE flag boolean;


 SET flag = IF( (select count(*) 
 from Test 
 where Pass = p_Pass and Mail = p_Mail) > 0, 1, 0);
 RETURN flag;

END;
go
DELIMITER ; 

SELECT login('Pass1', 'Email1');
```

Demo:
https://paiza.io/projects/sioJelUeAuqfrStgCe2h5w?language=mysql

Comment: @IliyanPetrov, you are welcome, happy to help. You can mark this answer as correct and you can vote it up if it helped you. Thanks! (https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: *"that makes sense"* @IliyanPetrov not really.. You should not be using password in the `WHERE` as that would allow [timing related attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) on the password/hash possible in the SQL engine..  As RDMS nowadays are designed to deliver very stabile timings for matches and non matches as most RDMS run data in RAM memory buffers..

Answer (score 0):

You want your procedure to return something  but you don't use 'return' in it

https://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/techniques/return-value-from-procedure

beside that, your code look very much vulnerable to SQL Injection

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68701/how-does-stored-procedure-prevents-sql-injection

Maybe you could consider doing this check in your application instead of inside the database

Comment: *"beside that, your code look very much vulnerable to SQL Injection"* No it's not vulnerable the topicstarters MySQL stored procedure code is safe against SQL injections assuming it would work..

Comment: but i agree about doing this in the application also the topicstarter should not be using `password` in the `WHERE` as that would allow [timing related attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) on the password/hash possible in the SQL engine.. As RDMS nowadays are designed to deliver very stabile timings for matches and non matches as most RDMS run data in RAM memory buffers..